# Generating Template Parameters at Compile Time

Tags: c++, c++11, embedded, c-preprocessor

I've created a class that looks like an array, but rather than holding the data in the program itself, it streams the byte from a file (to reduce RAM impact).  Now I've got all this working, but the programmer has to define the class using the following:

```
#define CreateReadOnlyBlock(name, location, size, ...)          \
template<>                                                      \
const unsigned int ReadOnlyBlock<location, size>::Data[]        \
    __asm__( ".readonly__" #location "__" #name)                \
    = { __VA_ARGS__ };                                          \
ReadOnlyBlock<location, size> name;
```

Example:

```
//A read only array of {0, 1, 2, 3}
CreateReadOnlyBlock(readOnlyArray, 0, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3);
```

Note that this is for an embedded processor, and the asm directive goes through a tool in the assembler to create the read-only-file.

So here's my question:  how can I eliminate the "location" and "size" variables?  I hate that the programmer has to type those in manually, and would much prefer some way of generating those at compile-time.  So instead of the programmer needing to type:

```
//A read only array at location 0 of {0, 1, 2, 3}
CreateReadOnlyBlock(readOnlyArray1, 0, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3); 
//A read only array at location 4 of {4, 5, 6, 7}
CreateReadOnlyBlock(readOnlyArray2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7);
```

They could just type:

```
CreateReadOnlyBlock(readOnlyArray1, 0, 1, 2, 3); 
CreateReadOnlyBlock(readOnlyArray2, 4, 5, 6, 7);
```

And the appropriate constants would be generated.  Basically I'm looking for some way to generate and place these constants based on previous definitions at compile time.  C++11 is fair game, I'm just not terribly familiar with it (something with constexpr seems plausible?).  Also, C-Preprocessor is okay too if it doesn't make it uglier than it already is.  Is this possible?

EDIT for clarity:

In the ReadOnlyBlock class there is this method:

```
    template<const int _location, const int _size> class ReadOnlyBlock
    {
        ...
        unsigned int operator[] (size_t index)
        {
            return LoadFromROM(index + _location);
        }
    }
```

There is an intrinsic interdependence between the location variable and the ROM file that I cannot think of how to break.  I *do* have complete control over the tool chain as well, however, but I need a way to pass the assembler tool how to construct the file as well as indicate to the C++ code where the blocks lie in the file.

Another EDIT:

The file and its blocks can be *quite* large, as much as 1k words, so a lot of preprocessor magic might collapse given that.  Also, thanks everyone for the help so far!

Comment: The `#location` in the `__asm__` part is really killing it. Do you really need that or would you be happy with a solution of the rest only?

Comment: Size is easy, but location would require context.  Template instantiation is a functional language, and the result of the instantiation can only vary based on what you pass in.  If you chain such blocks, or create the memory in one large template, it can be done.  Ie, create a `tuple` of read only arrays, each with a location and size, starting at some location, and packed.

Comment: So maybe I should've included the reason for that.  The overloaded [] operator in the ReadOnlyBlock class calls LoadFromROM(index + location);  The tool creates a read only file that has each block at each specified location, and the class knows to load from that spot.  I can't think of a way to eliminate that interdependence, but I do have full control over the tool as well as the access code, so changing it isn't out of the question.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed you use the string value of `location` at compile time, concatenate string literals including it, then pass the result to `__asm__`.  Does your `__asm__` support `constexpr` strings?  :)

Comment: I'm not actually sure.  I am using Clang 3.0 with a custom LLVM backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't see the full solution for generating the name (that `#location` fragment), but for the rest, I guess you could use something like this:

```
template< std::size_t Line >
struct current_location : current_location< Line - 1 > {};

template<>
struct current_location< 0 > : std::integral_constant< std::size_t, 0 > {};

#define NUMARGS(...) (sizeof((int[]){__VA_ARGS__})/sizeof(int))

#define CreateReadOnlyBlock(name, ...)                          \
template<>                                                      \
const unsigned int ReadOnlyBlock<                               \
    current_location<__LINE__-1>::value, NUMARGS(__VA_ARGS__)   \
>::Data[]                                                       \
    __asm__( ".readonly__" #name)                               \
    = { __VA_ARGS__ };                                          \
ReadOnlyBlock<current_location<__LINE__-1>::value,              \
              NUMARGS(__VA_ARGS__)> name;                       \
template<>                                                      \
struct current_location<__LINE__>                               \
    : std::integral_constant<std::size_t,                       \
        current_location<__LINE__-1>::value+NUMARGS(__VA_ARGS__)> \
{};
```

Comment: This is perfect!  Thank you so much.  I'm actually not convinced I need the #location anymore, since this seems to put the data into a solid sequential block anyways.  I'm a little worried that the compiler could re-order things though, which is where I would need the location identifier.  In that scenario, I would just put the location as the first index in the array and get the tool to remove it.  Not pretty, but hey it works!

Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe grasping a bit, but would it be possible with variadic templates instead of va_args? Something like

```
template <typename T1, ... TV>
class ReadOnlyBlock
{
    static unsigned int Data[sizeof(TV) + 1];
};
```

basically, anywhere you would need 'location', use T1. Anywhere you need 'size', use sizeof(TV) + 1. Don't have an appropriate compiler to test this out, but maybe it's something to consider...

Comment: It's not really the data that's killing me right now, but thanks for the suggestion!  I may convert it over to variadic templates later, I'm just more comfortable with the C Preprocessor and just trying to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It may help.
I've written some stuff to count blocks
can add `DEF_BLOCK(size)` befor block declaration. You may try rewrite my example to allocate data inside my blocks

```
template<size_t ID>
struct block_t
{
   enum{location = 0};
};

#define LAST_BLOCK struct last_block_t{enum{id=__COUNTER__-1};};

#define SPEC2(ID, SIZE) template<> struct block_t<ID>{enum{location = block_t<ID-1>::location + SIZE, prev_block = ID-1, size = SIZE};}
#define SPEC(ID, SIZE) SPEC2(ID, SIZE)

#define DEF_BLOCK(SIZE) SPEC(__COUNTER__, SIZE)

DEF_BLOCK(10);
DEF_BLOCK(11);
LAST_BLOCK;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   std::cout << block_t<last_block_t::id>::location << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the following holds:

- You don't use `__COUNTER__` elswhere
- All arrays have maximum length 5
- All arrays are defined in the very same file

Then you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>

#define VA_NARGS_IMPL(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, N, ...) N
#define VA_NARGS(...) VA_NARGS_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

template <int... Args>
struct arg_counter {
  enum { count = sizeof...(Args) };
};

#define INC_COUNTER1 arg_counter<-1>::count
#define INC_COUNTER2 arg_counter<-1, __COUNTER__>::count
#define INC_COUNTER3 arg_counter<-1, __COUNTER__, __COUNTER__>::count
#define INC_COUNTER4 arg_counter<-1, __COUNTER__, __COUNTER__, __COUNTER__>::count
#define INC_COUNTER5 arg_counter<-1, __COUNTER__, __COUNTER__, __COUNTER__, __COUNTER__>::count

#define INC_COUNTER_IMPL2(count, ...) INC_COUNTER ## count
#define INC_COUNTER_IMPL(count, ...) INC_COUNTER_IMPL2(count, __VA_ARGS__) 
#define INC_COUNTER(...) INC_COUNTER_IMPL(VA_NARGS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)

// removed: __asm__( ".readonly__" #location "__" #name)
#define CreateReadOnlyBlockImpl(name, location, size, ...)      \
  template<>                                                    \
  const unsigned int ReadOnlyBlock<location, size>::Data[]      \
    = { __VA_ARGS__ };                                          \
  ReadOnlyBlock<location, size> name;


#define CreateReadOnlyBlock(name, ...)                                  \
  CreateReadOnlyBlockImpl(name, __COUNTER__, INC_COUNTER(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__);

template<int Location, int Size> struct ReadOnlyBlock
{
  static const unsigned int Data[Size];
  int loc () const { return Location; }
  int size() const { return Size; }
};

CreateReadOnlyBlock(readOnlyArray1, 0, 1, 2, 3);
CreateReadOnlyBlock(readOnlyArray2, 4, 5, 6, 7);
CreateReadOnlyBlock(readOnlyArray3, 9);
CreateReadOnlyBlock(readOnlyArray4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

int main()
{
  std::cout << "@" << readOnlyArray1.loc() << ": " << readOnlyArray1.size() << '\n';
  std::cout << "@" << readOnlyArray2.loc() << ": " << readOnlyArray2.size() << '\n';
  std::cout << "@" << readOnlyArray3.loc() << ": " << readOnlyArray3.size() << '\n';
  std::cout << "@" << readOnlyArray4.loc() << ": " << readOnlyArray4.size() << '\n';
}
```

[On ideone this prints:](http://ideone.com/NGifJm)

```
@0: 4
@4: 4
@8: 1
@9: 5
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the arrays are as big as 1k words, but I really like this solution.  I should've clarified that, sorry.  I've edited my post.